# Is it possible to see comments made by a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, comments

If anyone could tell me how to see comments made by a Facebook Page on other page's that would be great. When I go to a particular page I can see all the comments they make on their own one, but I'm more interested in seeing the likes/comments they make on other pages - if that's possible!

Thanks.